# PEP8 conformance for type annotated return types in overlength lines

Tags: python-3.x, pep8

I use Python's type annotations to specify the return type of a function. In this example the last line with the return type is to long.

```
def cut_by_row_keep_group(data: pandas.DataFrame,
                          group_column,
                          n_pieces: int,
                          sort_kind: str = 'quicksort') -> list[pandas.DataFrame]:
                                                                               ^^^
```

The checker tells me correct

```
$ pycodestyle bandas.py
bandas.py:20:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
```

I don't know how to fix this in a PEP8 conformant way. I tried `autopep8`. But it ignores it also when I reduce the default maximum line length to 70.

```
$ autopep8 bandas.py --diff --max-line-length 70
```

`black` as an alternative to `autopep8` does offer a solution, but I won't present it here as an answer. This is because `black` does a lot more then just PEP8 and also has some other disadvantages, e.g. replace `'` with `"` and indentation reducing readability of the code. As my title states I am interested in a PEP8 conformant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put annotations into type aliases. For instance:

```py
DF = pandas.DataFrame
```